# In the back of the body/at the back

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

This is, I believe, crucial, because one might misunderstood the slight difference of **prepositions**; and these are:

> There is a wound **in** the back of my body.(any part,but still the backside)
>
> There is a wound **at** the back of my body.(anal part)

Could you please confirm this if I'm correct?

Comment: Apart from both should be 'a wound', I don't see what you're asking. 'In' would seem better than 'at' but neither conveys any further distinction as to precisely *where*.

Comment: Ok I'll put in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one would further describe which portion of your body you have a wound

> I have a wound **on** my back. *(this is literally on your back)*
>   I have a wound **on** the back of my legs.
>   I have a wound **on** my bottom.

If you say

> I have a wound **in** my back.
>   I have a wound **in** the back of my leg.
>   I have a wound **in** my bottom.

It would be understood that something is **piercing** your back, bottom, or leg, e.g. a knife.

**At** would not usually be used by itself.

Comment: Got it, but how do you say if it is at the anal part(preposition)?

Comment: It's the same, as in my examples, "***on*** *for a wound*", "***in*** *my bottom*" for a piercing.  Do not confuse it with "***at*** *the back of the train*" which is a long object, your bottom is hopefully not as long.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that sounds uncomfortable.

For starters, I'm not sure you want to use *wound*.  You get a wound from being *wounded*, which is to say, accidentally or deliberately pierced or cut by some object.  While it's certainly *possible* to be wounded on your anus, that would probably make an interesting story.

Instead if you are talking about some other kind of medical condition, *lesion* is probably the more accurate term:

> **[lesion](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lesion)** (n): A region in an organ or tissue which has suffered damage through injury or disease, such as a wound, ulcer, abscess, or tumor.

*Lesion* is kind of a medical term, so more commonly, and depending what it looked like and what caused it, you would describe it as a *blister*, *boil*, *cut*, *bruise*, *sore*, *rash*, *tear*, or just an *infection*.

If you are talking to a doctor, I would recommend being specific about where it is.  Otherwise, if you are speaking *euphemistically* in (relatively) polite company, then *"on my bottom"* is close enough.  Few people really want to know too much detail about something like that.